# not loading css & jQuery after publish - asp.net mvc (error 403)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

hello guy's i publish my website on server  but my css & jquery not loaded 
mr error in incpect has

[image]

Comment: Don't use the flickr API to server to server jQuery, you're better off using a CDN. What happens if you try and browse to the problematic files directly. Please include the code where you are referencing these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 2 cents...
This seems to me more of access issue.

1. Make sure you are not using absolute paths in you code to access your CSS & JQuery files. Instead use relative path - I did some [search here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662136/3590235) for you
2. When you deploy your app to server (after publishing), the new server environment may be restricting your access to some resources (for ex. hyperlink addresses). So change location or grant the appropriate permissions.
   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The response code 403 indicates that you have not provided proper authentication required by the flickr API. Look at https://www.flickr.com/services/api/ as to how you should implement the authentication.