# Referring .htc file from CSS in ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to add a htc file in css. The solution structure is:

[image]

I am in /Styles/QTip/jquery.qtip.css and from there I am referring the PIE.htc as:

```
behavior: url('../HTC/PIE.htc');
```

But it is not working.

Also after running the application from VS2010 if I browse

http://localhost:2873/Styles/QTip/jquery.qtip.css

Then browser opens the css file but if I browse the URL

http://localhost:2873/Styles/HTC/PIE.htc

I am getting **The resource cannot be found**.

What will be the right path of this htc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an absolute path or a full URL reference as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005442/where-do-i-put-the-pie-htc-file-for-making-ie-work-with-css3-when-im-using-ca) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870870/css3pie-in-mvc-where-to-place-the-pie-htc-file).

Answer (score 1):

You need to go up another folder...

```
behavior: url('../HTC/PIE/PIE.htc');
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I am still in hangover.